# Triangle drawn in region bounded by $x$-axis and polynomial with all real roots: supremum of ratio of areas?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polynomials

A triangle is drawn in a region bounded by the $x$-axis and a polynomial curve with all real roots, with one side of the triangle on the $x$-axis, as shown in this example:

[image]

> What is the supremum of the ratio  $R$ of the triangle's area to the region's area?

(We require that the polynomial has all real roots, because [otherwise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648043/398708) the answer would be trivial: the supremum would be $1$, for example with $y=x-x^n$ and letting $n\to\infty$.)

I considered the largest area triangle drawn in the region bounded by the $x$-axis and the polynomial $y=(-1)^{n-1}(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2-1\right)^n, a>1$, from $x=-1$ to $x=1$.

[image]

Numerical investigation suggests that for any given $a$ value, the ratio $R$ is maximized when $n\approx 1.880001a^2$.

$\color{blue}{a=10}$:

$\space R\approx0.8953810$ with $y=(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{187}}$

$\space R\approx0.8953823$ with $y=-(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{188}}$

$\space R\approx0.8953822$ with $y=(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{189}}$

$\color{blue}{a=100}$:

$\space R\approx0.8955295$ with $y=-(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{18799}}$

$\space R\approx0.8955296$ with $y=(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{18800}}$

$\space R\approx0.8955295$ with $y=-(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{100}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{18801}}$

$\color{blue}{a=1000}$:

$\space R\approx0.89553095$ with $y=(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{1000}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{1880000}}$

$\space R\approx0.89553105$ with $y=(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{1000}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{1880001}}$

$\space R\approx0.89553101$ with $y=(x^2-1)\left(\left(\frac{x}{1000}\right)^2-1\right)^{\color{red}{1880002}}$

I conjecture that $\text{sup}(R)$ is approached when $a\to\infty$ (for each value of $a$, we choose the value of $n$ that maximizes $R$), and that $\text{sup}(R)\approx 0.895531$.

Comment: A version of this question was asked at MSE two days ago with an accepted answer: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4648043/237).

Comment: The difference between the two questions is that, the other question allows regions bounded by any polynomial (including those with non-real roots) and any line (not just the $x$-axis).

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I now realize that my last sentence ("I posted this question on...) was misleading. I posted two questions on MSE: the first was the one you linked to, the second was the same as this question. I deleted the second question. (It indeed received no answer and few views. Well, to be precise, someone answered it but then deleted their answer because they misread the question.) I'm sorry, didn't mean to be misleading.

Comment: Interesting question. It is useful to cross-reference when posting related questions.

Comment: Now at version 14 of this question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Point taken. I'll try not to abuse the edit function.

Comment: Is the optimal triangle  in your examples always has vertices $(-1, 0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$? For a fixed $a$ and large $n$ this triangle does not fit into the region bounded by the curve (this is equivalent to the inequality $(1 - x^2)(1 - (x/a)^2)^n > 1 - x$ on $[0,1]$)

Comment: @PavelGubkin The optimal triangle does not always have vertices at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ (but it always has a vertex at $(0,1)$). The length of the (horizontal) base of the optimal triangle is at most $2$; it depends on $a$ and $n$.

Comment: It's easier for you to figure out the limit case if you study $(1-x^2)e^{-ax^2}$ around $a=1.88$.

Comment: And it may be that the metric you chose is too hard for a proof. I think looking for polynomials $P$ symmetric in $x$, with $P(-1)=1, P(1)=-1$ and $P(x)\ge 1-|x|$ in $[-1,1]$ that minimize $\int_{-1}^{1}P(x) d x$ would be more natural and much more amenable to a proof.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Thank you for your suggestions. Did you mean $P(-1)=P(1)=0$ ? (If $P(1)=-1$ then $P(x)$ cannot be $\ge 1-|x|$ at $x=1$.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I meant $P(-1)=P(1)=0$. Thank you.

Comment: But actually that last condition is not even necessary or useful. So, to recap, I think a problem which is very similar to the original, but for which it may be relativily easy to work out and explicity solution, would be that of minimizing $\int_0^1 \big(P(x)e^{-ax^2}-1+x\big)^2dx$ over real $a\ge 0$ and $P$ of the form $P(x)=\prod_{1\le i \le n} (1-a_i x^2)$ for $0\le a_i \le1$.